# Conditionally deserialize JSON string or array property to C# object using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a defined C# object based off a very complex JSON I'm getting from a third party API. Here's a piece of it:

```
{"alarmSummary":"NONE"}
```

The corresponding property in C# would be:

```
public string alarmSummary {get; set;}
```

And I would get this converted by using my typical JSONConvert from JSON.NET:

```
var alarms = JSONConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

However, the API will put alarms in this format, as an array, and "NONE" when there aren't any as a string:

```
{"alarmSummary" : ["AHHH Something went wrong!!", "I'm on fire!!"]}
```

Which means in C# it would need to be:

```
public string[] alarmSummary {get; set;}
```

If I could, I would just have the JSONConvert deserialize the "NONE" string into an array of just one entry. Is there a way to set conditions on this property, or will I have to take the whole complex JSON string and hand convert it?

Answer (score 4):

This one should be easy - you can set your `alarmSummary` as object and then have separate property that evaluates `alarmSummary` and returns null or array depending on the value.

```
    public object alarmSummary { get; set; }

    protected string[] alarmSummaryCasted
    {
        get
        {
            if (alarmSummary is String)
                return null;
            else
                return (string[]) alarmSummary;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What method would you use to deserialize?

Comment: @Edin I was suggesting this if he has `alarmSummary` as property on POCO class and deserializes instance of that class (this is what I do with ServiceStack.Text JSON library). If he is directly deserializing to variable, what you suggest in your answer is better, plus it also uses specific functionality of Json.Net library.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting only those two combinations, you could make use of the dynamic keyword and check deserialized object:

```
string json = "{\"alarmSummary\":\"NONE\"}";
//string json = "{\"alarmSummary\" : [\"AHHH Something went wrong!!\", \"I'm on fire!!\"]}";

string[] alarmSummary;
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
if (obj.alarmSummary.Type == JTokenType.Array)
   alarmSummary = obj.alarmSummary.ToObject<string[]>();
else
   alarmSummary = new[] { (string)obj.alarmSummary.ToObject<string>() };
```