# Converter that uses generics to parse json model

Tags: c#, .net, json, generics, json.net

I have a converter class that receives json in input, here are 2 valid examples:

```js
{
  "method": "Model",
  "payload": {
    "key": "value"
  }
}
```

and

```js
{
  "method": "OtherModel",
  "payload": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

In C#, I have classes mapped to each possible model:

```cs
public class Model
{
  public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class OtherModel
{
  public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I need a generic converter

How can I use the string value in the `method` of the JSON to convert in a generic way the content of the payload field?

Is using a huge switch the only way? This is the prototype I have so far but there are hundreds of different models so it will grow quite large...

```cs
public IResult ParseJson(string json)
{
  Regex regexMessageName = new Regex("\"messageName\": \"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Compiled);
  var messageName = regexMessageName.Match(json).Groups[1].Value;
  switch (messageName)
  {
    case "Model":
      var raw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData<Model>>(json);
      return new LogInfoRequestResult<Model> { Raw = raw };
    case "OtherModel":
      var raw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData<OtherModel>>(json);
      return new LogInfoRequestResult<OtherModel> { Raw = raw };

  }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar situation and this is how I solved it. In my case there where only about 40 or so cases.

Comment: What about deserializing `Payload` to a `Dictionary<string, string>` ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3657466/10608418? You can search your assembly for a class with your `messageName` as name. Then you can use that to deserialize the json with the right model

Comment: @Cid hmm could be a solution...but I'd really prefer typed because the values are not always all strings

Comment: @Knoop Thanks, yes something similar to this. I hope the performance would not be too bad with reflection though...

Comment: @ibizia that would depend a bit. For starters you could create a dictionary with `messageName` as key and types you've already searched for. In case all the models share some common ancestor/interface or specific naming convention you could build that dictionary on start-up in one go

Comment: @Knoop And how do you instanciate a `new LogInfoRequestResult<T>` from a type that is in a Dictionary<string, Type> ?

Comment: @BrianRogers that would just move the switch to the converter...

Comment: @ibiza is the `method` always equal to the name of the class you want to instantiate?  Or could it be different?

Comment: @BrianRogers I control the name of the C# class (model) so it can be the same (I think it is better to be)

Comment: BTW, I hope you only need to handle the c# aspect of this. If you need to handle a json schema that describes these different objects, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53884747/3094533) I've got to my question might help with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want complete control of your classes, and allow them to evolve independently, then you can have one base class that owns the Method, and then as many subclasses as you want with their own definition of the payload.

First, parse into the baseclass, just to get a strongly typed deserialization of `Method`

Then, there are a lot of patterns to address branching logic.

- If you have 1-2 cases, an `if` statement is fine
- If you have 3-5 cases, you can use a `switch`
- If you have 6-10 cases, you can create a `dictionary` that maps method name to class type
- If you have more than that, you can use the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and pass an interface around

Here's an example of how you could write the code:

```cs
var json = @"{
    'method': 'Model',
    'payload': {
        'key': 'value'
    }
}";

var modelBase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelBase>(json);

var methodMapping = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    {MethodTypes.Model.ToString(), typeof(Model)},
    {MethodTypes.OtherModel.ToString(), typeof(OtherModel)},
};

Type methodClass = methodMapping[modelBase.Method];

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, methodClass);
```

> **Note**: Since we're programmatically determining the correct type, it's hard to [pass to a generic `<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1292480/1366033), so this uses the overload of `DeserializeObject` that takes `type` as a param

And here are the classes that model incoming messages

```cs
public enum MethodTypes
{
    Model,
    OtherModel
}

public class ModelBase
{
    public string Method { get; set; }
}

public class Model : ModelBase
{
    public ModelInfo Payload { get; set; }

    public class ModelInfo
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
}

public class OtherModel : ModelBase
{
    public ModelInfo Payload { get; set; }

    public class ModelInfo
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### `Dictionary<string,string>`

If your data is always going to be `"foo":"bar"` or `"key":"value"` .... `string:string`, then Cid's suggesting to use `Dictionary<string,string> Payload` makes a lot of sense.  Then figure out however you want to map from that c# class in a c# constructor that returns whatever type you want.

#### Additional Resources:

- [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/1366033)
- [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/1366033)
- [JSON.NET - Conditional Type Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7816780/1366033)
- [Conditionally deserialize JSON string or array property to C# object using JSON.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35782400/1366033)

Comment: The enum gives you a way to independently name incoming method names with what class you want to map ti to. If they're always going to be in sync, you could just use `{nameof(Model), typeof(Model)}`, which will both be run at compile time, so should be pretty performant compared to a reflection lookup of class name.

Answer (score 2):

You can instanciate an object of the expected class using `Activator.CreateInstance()`, then populate it with `JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`

In example :

```
Type t = Type.GetType($"NameSpaceName.{messageName}"); // this must be a fully qualified name
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, obj);
```